# StandardOutput string from C# Console Application

Tags: powershell, console-application, system.diagnostics

I have a .Net Framework console application written in C# which is run from a Powershell script. I want to be able to get a value from the console application as a result of running the console app.

As a crude example, I have this...

```
namespace PlainConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result = 0;

            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "one":
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                case "two":
                    result = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    result = -1;
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is run using the following Powershell script (I am very new to Powershell):

```
$consoleApp = "C:\Temp\PlainConsoleApp.exe"
$arg1 = "one"

$submitprocess = start-process $consoleApp $arg1 -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow

$result = $submitprocess.ExitCode
Write-Host "exit code: " + $result

exit $submitprocess.ExitCode
```

So, when I run this I can see I get the return result in the `ExitCode`... However I have been advised to look at `$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`. If I then try to run something like this:

```
$consoleApp = "C:\Temp\PlainConsoleApp.exe"
$arg1 = "one"

$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = $consoleApp
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = $arg1
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
Write-Host "stderr: $stderr"
Write-Host "exit code: " + $p.ExitCode
```

I still only seem to get the return value from the `ExitCode`. Also, I would like to be able to return either a bool or a string but can only seem to get integers returned from the console app??

Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the Console App to something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result;

        switch (args[0])
        {
            case "1":
                result = "one";
                break;
            case "2":
                result = "two";
                break;
            case "3":
                result = "three";
                break;
            case "4":
                result = "four";
                break;
            case "5":
                result = "five";
                break;
            default:
                result = "null";
                break;
        }

        Console.Out.Write(result);
    }
```

And now call the app like this:

```
$console = "C:\Dev\Local Projects\PlainConsoleApp\PlainConsoleApp\bin\Debug\PlainConsoleApp.exe"
$arg1 = "5"


$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = $console
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = $arg1
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
Write-Host "stdout:" $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

And that seems to do the job:

[image]